# TypeScript: Object as class property (non-static or static)

Tags: typescript, types

How I should annotate `foo` and `BAR` in below `ExampleClass`?

```
class ExampleClass {
    private foo = {
        one: 1,
        two: 2
    };

    private static BAR = {
        one: 'one',
        two: 'three'
    }
}
```

Case when it's important:

[image]

Text version:

```
import { Vue, Component, Prop } from 'vue-property-decorator';

@Component
export default class Bootstrap4AlertsCodeGenerator extends Vue {

  static CONTEXT_CSS_CLASSES: object = {
    PRIMARY: 'primary',
    SECONDARY: 'secondary',
    SUCCESS: 'success',
  };

  contextCssClass: string = Bootstrap4AlertsCodeGenerator.CONTEXT_CSS_CLASSES.SECONDARY;

  public get isSelectContextCssClassRadiobuttonActive(): (contextCssClass: string) => boolean {
    return contextCssClass => this.contextCssClass === contextCssClass;
  }
}
```

Error:

```
TS2339: Property 'SECONDARY' does not exist on type 'object'.
```

Comment: You don't need to. What is the concrete problem you're trying to solve? Are you asking us how to define interfaces? https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/interfaces.html

Comment: @JB Nizet, than you for the comment. I added screenshot with concrete problem.

Comment: Post code and errors as **text**.

Comment: @JB Nizet, O'K, done.

Comment: Remove `: object`.

Comment: @JB Nizet, of course it will work if to remove annotation. But I want to annotate it because it why I migrated to TypeScript.

Comment: Then you need to learn TypeScript. The inferred type of the variable is more precise and correct than `object`.